# WSO2 SOAP add new tenant

Tags: wso2, wso2-identity-server

I use `services/TenantMgtAdminService.TenantMgtAdminServiceHttpsSoap12Endpoint/` endpoint in WSO2 IS 5.9.0, I can create a tenant successfully with `addTenant` method.
What's the meaning of the return id if I send a specific id from envelope in `<xsd:tenantId>1</xsd:tenantId>`

My response

```xml
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope">
   <soapenv:Body>
      <ns:addTenantResponse xmlns:ns="http://services.mgt.tenant.carbon.wso2.org">
         <ns:return>9ab460b9-1176-4d97-ad84-e6fbbd31a1fb</ns:return>
      </ns:addTenantResponse>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, we can't set the tenantId when a tenant is created. The tenantId passed in the request will be ignored and a tenant id will be created according to the internal implementation.

The returned id of the **addTenant** method is just UID.

```
<ns:return>9ab460b9-1176-4d97-ad84-e6fbbd31a1fb</ns:return>
```

There is no functional use-case from this. It is used to get the tenant theme for the management console.

If you want to get the id of the newly created tenant you can use **getTenant** SOAP method.